# How I create an USB entry on EFI boot?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, efi

I bought a second hand Samsung Ultrabook N530U3C which the boot is not working well. The previous owner managed to install linux and make it boot, but the USB entry on the EFI boot is not working. I want to boot on a stickdrive to install another OS

I tried to use the efibootmanager but I don't know how to create an USB entry there.

Do someone know s how I create an USB entry on EFI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to bios setting >>> In ADVANCED tab, disable fast boot. In BOOT tab, enable UEFI Boot.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your answer, but my problem is that I'm unable to boot any USB drive on it. There is no menu option on the EFI to boot on a USB drive

Comment: go to bios setting >>> In ADVANCED tab, disable fast boot.
    In BOOT tab, enable UEFI Boot.

Comment: Accepting the answer because of the comments, but please edit your answer to reflect the comment

Answer (score -1):

- go to bios setting >>> In ADVANCED tab, disable fast boot.
- In BOOT tab, enable UEFI Boot.